# Error in maven assembly:single target: request to write 8192 bytes exceeds size in header

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

This project compile's and packages' successfully, but assembly does not work.  Here is the pom.xml fragment:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>appminer_hive-${version}</finalName>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/deploy-packaging.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Here is the deploy-packaging.xml:

```
 <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>deploy</id>
  <baseDirectory>etl/appminer/hive</baseDirectory>
  <formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
  </formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/lib</directory>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
<files>
<file>
    <source>${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</source>
    <outputDirectory>libs</outputDirectory>
</file>
  </files>
 </assembly>
```

Here is the output:

```
Results :

  [INFO] Building Apps Classifier Hive Workflow
  [INFO]    task-segment: [assembly:single]
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] [assembly:single {execution: default-cli}]
  [INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/deploy-packaging.xml
  [INFO] hive/lib/ already added, skipping
  [INFO] Building tar : /shared/git2/etl/appminer/hive/target/appminer_hive-1.0-deploy.tar.gz
  [INFO] hive/lib/ already added, skipping
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive deploy: Problem creating TAR: request to write '8192' bytes exceeds size in header of '9646203' bytes

  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Trace
  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive deploy: Problem creating TAR: request to write '8192' bytes exceeds size in header of '9646203' bytes
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
      at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
      at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
      at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
      at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
      at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
      at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
      at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
      at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
```

Comment: Out of interest, does `zip` fail too?

Comment: i'll try that and report back.

Comment: That's working better!  That error disappeared. Now I apparently have a recursive definition of file inclusion, working through that.

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to state what you're trying to achieve. It looks like a `jar-with-dependencies` kind of setup...

Comment: @HoundDog: yes it is a jar  target and we do have the dependency-jars target too.

Comment: Which version of maven-assembly-plugin are you using?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this @javadba?

Comment: @Will  No idea - been a long time ;)

Comment: Oh well, thanks for following up! Anyway, a colleague encountered a similar error in a Linux environment.

Comment: Maven itself provides part of a solution. It should output something like:
`[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :failed-step`
If you can solve the failed step (possibly by running it in isolation), you can continue from there using the above command. If you don't need to run the failed step at all, you can continue from the following step; just replace the `failed-step` above with the appropriate one.